# Is friction a conservative force when a ball rolls down an inclined plane(pure rolling)?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

My book says friction is non dissipative for a cylinder rolling down an inclined plane,so is it conserved?

Comment: friction here plays the role of force of constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot view friction as a conservative force in this situation. Here is why:

We know that for a conservative force $F$ we can define a potential energy function $U$ such that 
$$F=-\frac{\text d U}{\text d x}$$

and a consequence of this is that the work done by this force is given by
$$W=-\Delta U$$

However, static friction does no net work on the cylinder. Therefore for all instances of rolling here $W=0$. This means we must have a constant potential energy, which means that $F=0$. This is a contradiction, since we assumed we had a static friction force. Therefore static friction cannot be conservative.